# Showing that $\int_{\partial^+ D_1(0) } \frac{2}{z^2 + 4iz - 1} dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{\sin(t) + 2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that
$$ \int_{\partial^+ D_1(0) } \frac{2}{z^2 + 4iz - 1} dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{\sin(t) + 2},$$
where $\partial^+ D_1(0)$ is the positively oriented unit circle.
This seems like it would have to do with the imaginary parts of $z^2$ and $4iz$ cancelling out somehow. I tried parametrizing the path as $\cos t + i\sin t$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ and using $z^2 = cos(2t)  + i\sin(2t)$, but that does not seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: what does it get you instead?

Comment: The integrand becomes $\frac{2(-\sin(t) + i \cos(t))}{\cos(2t) + i\sin(2t) - 4\sin(t) + 4i\cos(t) - 1}$, which does not seem like much of a simplification.

Comment: As the answer indicates, it was the correct way to go, you just had to push through :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the path $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi)$, so that we can write
$$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{[0,2\pi)}f(\gamma(t))\gamma(t)'dt$$
where $f(z)$ is the function to be integrated. We get
$$f(\gamma(t))\gamma(t)'=\frac{2ie^{it}}{e^{2it}+4ie^{it}-1}=\frac{2i}{e^{it}+4i-e^{-it}}=\frac{2i}{4i+2i\sin(t)}=\frac{1}{2+\sin(t)}$$